# How to Rotate an imageview inside a UIScrollView iOS?

Tags: ios, uiscrollview, uiimageview, rotation, uigesturerecognizer

I have a `UIScrollView` which has an `UIImageView` in it. I need to be able to to rotate the image. rotation gestures are being intercepted by the ScrollView.

```
    self.scrollView = [[ScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.bounds];
    self.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = NO;
    self.scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.scrollView.decelerationRate = 0.0; 
    self.scrollView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    self.scrollView.layer.borderWidth = 2.0;
    self.scrollView.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor];


    [self addSubview:self.scrollView];

    //self.imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.scrollView.frame];
    self.imageView = [[UIRotateImageView alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
    self.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    self.imageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    [self.scrollView addSubview:self.imageView];

    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = CGRectGetWidth(self.scrollView.frame) / CGRectGetWidth(self.imageView.frame);
    self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale = 1.0;
    self.scrollView.maximumZoomScale = 20.0;
    [self.scrollView setZoomScale:self.scrollView.minimumZoomScale];


- (UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView{
    return self.imageView;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean when you rotate the screen, you wanna resize the imageView?

Comment: instead of scrollView i suggest you to use pinch gesture which look more even and with pinch gesture you can easily use rotatoin gesture.

Comment: @EbruGüngör i need rotate image using geture. only imageview

Comment: @DivyanshuSharma i tried but not getting result. Please provide some sample code

Comment: why you need scrollview ?

Comment: @AlokRao For multiple image :(